# Python: Performing Mathematical Functions between IP Address Octets

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm trying to perform the following:

```
firstoctet * 256 + secondoctet = * 256 + thirdoctet = * 256 + fourthoctet = x
```

When I use this as an example :

```
64.233.187.99 (google.com)
64 * 256 + 233 = * 256 + 187 = * 256 + 99 = http://1089059683/
```

Can someone please provide a method as to how this can be done? The mathematical sequence is no problem, i'm just unsure as to how I can take the octet values out of the decimal points to perform the math functions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is an `ipaddress` module you can use. What are you trying to do with the ip adresses exactly? Don't solve stuff that is already available (unless thats what you're trying to do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on Python 3.3 or higher, you can leverage [the `ipaddress` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) to avoid reinventing the wheel, and it even provides a useful view as `bytes` that `int.from_bytes` can efficiently convert to a real `int`:

```
from ipaddress import IPv4Address

ip_as_addr = IPv4Address("64.233.187.99")
ip_as_int = int.from_bytes(ip_as_addr.packed, 'big')
print(ip_as_int, hex(ip_as_int))
```

gets you output of `1089059683 0x40e9bb63`.

You could do this by hand if you really wanted to, I just like the self-documenting aspect of the above code. If Py 3.3+ isn't an option, you can get the same results with:

```
octets = map(int, "64.233.187.99".split('.'))
ip_as_int = sum(octet << ((3 - i) * 8) for i, octet in enumerate(octets))
```

That just splits the octets apart, converts them to `int`, then shifts each of them left by 24, 16, 8 and 0 bits (to align the octets properly), which then allows `sum` to combine them into a single `int`.

Comment: Nice answer and good insight into what the OP probably wants to do.

Answer (score 0):

Convert an IP address string to a list of integers like this:

```
ip_as_string = "64.233.187.99"
ip_as_ints = [int(a) for a in ip_as_string.split('.')]
```

`ip_as_ints` will be [64, 233, 187, 99].

I will guess that the mathematical expression that you intend to perform is RPN for converting the byte sequence from a base-256 representation to a single number.  (Thanks to ShadowRanger for showing this).  You can obtain that single number easily as follows:

```
x = functools.reduce(lambda x,y: (x << 8) | y, ip_as_ints, 0)
print(x)
```

x is 1089059683.